# Can I right click in Ubuntu on Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

How can we right click with the touchscreen?  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the multi-touch input for right click is not functional. You can however, right click with the aid of the Onboard keyboard. Simply open onboard, click the mouse pointer, and then the right leaning cursor, and the next click will be a right click.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/UsingTheDevice